# Binding column of datagridview to content of list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have the following code.

```
public struct pixel
{
    public string xVal;
    public string yVal;
    public string distVal;
    public string locationXVal;
    public string locationYVal;
    public string locationZVal;
};
```

And then, i have a binding list of pixels

> private BindingList pixelList = new
>   BindingList();

After that, I bind it to a datagridview

> pointValuesList.DataSource = pixelList;

Adding:

> ```
>         pixel item = new pixel();
>
>         item.locationXVal = distCorXYZ.X.ToString("N3");
>         item.locationYVal = distCorXYZ.Y.ToString("N3");
>         item.locationZVal = distCorXYZ.Z.ToString("N3");
>
>         pixelList.Add(item);
> ```

When I add something on the list, the rows of the datagridview increase but no contents where added on the column. How would i be able to bind each column of the datagridview to the contents of the list. say for example:
1. First column is bound to pixelList[0].xVal and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: usually the databinding in a `DataGridView` works the way that each  **property** is bound to a column of 1 element in  a list. Are you trying to transpose the `DataGridView` ?

Comment: add `{get;set;}` after each field

Comment: What if I have different numbers of column and property? will it not work?

Comment: up to now you don't have any **property** you have only fields as @LeiYang also wrote.

Comment: Based on my post I said that "when i add something on the list". Im sorry that i do not show this on the post but I am indeed adding property. Sorry But still it does not show anything

Comment: Maybe this one pixelList doesn't have any content value. that's why your datagrid return nothing.

Comment: is `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true? and in your code, type `pixel` is not used at all, you just declared a **variable** called pixelList which is actually type of BindingList

Comment: Did you add a value to this list? BindingList pixelList = new BindingList().. Check it out....

Comment: I edited the post to show how I am adding values to pixellist

Comment: i tried your code out. and is working. and `private BindingList pixelList = new BindingList();` does not compile and need a generic version. I just suspect you're not pasting your actual code at all.

Comment: when i am typing at the textbox of stackoverflow new bindinglist has a generic.. i don`t know why stackoverflow is filtering it after I am clicking save.

Comment: I already solved it. Need to use accessors (get, set) for binding to work. Thank you!

Comment: "but I am indeed adding property" No, unfortunately you don't! you should read up on the difference between property and field. This is what we talked about in the beginning. Happy to hear that you solved it